# Minimum permissions to work with different virtualenvs in Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am setting up a PC with different virtual environments for Python develoment. The environments are set up and should not be messed with. A user with no root access is expected to write and test some Python code on this PC.

How the file permissions should be set up so that this no-root-access user could switch between the enviroments to activate the different sets of modules to test their code, but without ability to mess those environments up (ie, by adding new modules or removing existing ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readable, but not writeable. :-)

A virtualenv is simply a place where a Python interpreter with a private library can be found. You can put your virtualenvs into a directory that the user can read (and change to), but has no write permissions. They will be able to use the python interpreter, but not change anything within the virtualenv.

Comment: Well, the respective folders are indeed readable. I expected that workon command will simply do, but it gives error as if there is no such emvironment set up.

Comment: "workon" is part of virtualenvwrapper which activates a virtualenv in a pre-defined location and runs some hooks. I guess your problem is that workon can't find the virtualenvs because they are not in `~/.virtualenvs`. To make `workon` work, you need to set `WORKON_HOME` to the directory which contains your virtualenvs.

Alternatively, you can just use the activate script, e.g. `source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate` – workon does basically that.